# Get back to basics. How do I get back into C++?

Tags: c++

I haven't used `C++` since college.  Even though I've wanted to I haven't needed to do any until I started wanting to write plugins for `Launchy`.

> Is there a good book to read to get back into it?

My experience since college is mainly `C#` and recently `ruby`. I bought some book for `C#` developers and it ended up being on how to write `C++` with `CLI`. While a good book it wasn't quite what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to get back into C++ is to jump in.  You can't learn a real language without spending any serious time in a country where they speak it.  I wouldn't try to learn a programming language without spending time coding in it either.

I wouldn't recommend learning C first though.  That's a good way to pick up some bad habits in C++.

Answer (score 10):

My favorites are Effective C++, More Effective C++, and Effective STL by Scott Meyers. Also C++ Coding Standards by Sutter and Alexandrescu.

Answer (score 6):

I haven't tried it myself but have heard from people and sources I trust that "Accelerated C++" by Koenig and Moo is a good book for people who want to pick up C++ quickly. Compared to the more traditional route of learning C first then C++ as a kind of C with classes the K+M approach helps you become productive quickly while avoiding pitfalls and bad habits associated with the legacy of the language.

Answer (score 2):

A good starting place is "Thinking in C++" by Bruce Eckel, I've rarely had anyone complain about the book. Well written and also has a version available online.

Comment: Very effective as a starting guide. There are no fundamental mistakes in the guide, except that it should emphasize a little more the use of libraries (eg. boost). To summarize, a good starting point, but it should not be the last word about modern C++ practices.

Answer (score 2):

Another online book that I pick up whenever I need to get back into C++ is "C++ In Action" by Bartosz Milewski. Its [online](http://www.relisoft.com/book/index.htm) at his site.

Comment: This book is really great. I can also recommend it. Its not just about c++. Its also promotes good programming practices with very clean code illustrations.

Answer (score 1):

[The C++ Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201700735) by Bjarne Stroustrup covers C++ in depth. Bjarne is the inventor of C++. It also provides insights into why the language is the way it is. Some people find the book a little terse. I found it to be an enjoyable read. If you have done some C++ before it's a great place to start. It is by no means a beginners book on C++.

Answer (score 1):

My book recommendations:

**Essential C++** (Lippman)
**C++ Common Knowledge: Essential Intermediate Programming** (Dewhurst)
...and I second the **Effective C++** suggestion above.

A very handy alternative to buying books in meatspace is to subscribe to a service like [Safari Books Online](http://techbus.safaribooksonline.com/home). For a not unreasonable monthly fee you'll get access to all of the above books plus a bajillion others. If you desire fast random access to more than a couple books, it pretty much pays for itself. It's an easy case to make if you want to convince your employer to pay for it.

Beyond that, sit yourself in front of an IDE that has a C++ code completion feature (I use Eclipse/CDT most of the time).